# Does truesight + the Detect Magic spell defeat the Nystul's Magic Aura spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, illusion, special-senses

Suppose I suspect that an object is magical. I cast [*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic), but I see no magic aura on it.

However, I'm still suspicious, and now I begin to suspect that the aura has been hidden by [*Nystul's Magic Aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura). I happen to have a [*Gem of Seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gem-of-seeing), so I activate it and then once again use my action to see magic auras while peering through the gem at the suspicious object, this time with the [truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Truesight) granted by the gem, which among other things allows me to "automatically detect visual illusions".

Will the combination of truesight and *Detect Magic* allow me to see a magic aura hidden by *Nystul's Magic Aura*, or at least allow me to perceive the presence of an illusion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No, *Nystul's Magic Aura* still works against truesight and *detect magic*

Part of what [*Nystul’s Magic Aura*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/arcanists-magic-aura) does is make “divination spells reveal false information about it.” Both [*Detect Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/detect-magic) and [*True Seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) are Divination spells, so they reveal false information – separately or in combination.

In the case of a creature whose truesight does not come from a spell, as in the example of a [*Gem of Seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/gem-of-seeing), this also doesn't work. *Nystul’s Magic Aura* does not create a "visual illusion" that truesight can detect – it specifically misdirects "divination spells", not visual senses.

Similarly, for a creature whose ability to detect magic is not spell-based, *Nystul’s Magic Aura* changes the way the target "appears to spells and magical effects [...] that detect magical auras".

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but in my question I specified that the truesight was from a magic item, not a divination spell. (I just picked it randomly as an example of a way to gain truesight, I wasn't specifically trying to avoid this issue.)

Comment: I think it would make a difference, because the truesight from a gem of seeing isn't a spell.